# How to use dump and restore to 'clone' a Linux OS drive

Tags: linux, clone, restore, dump

You can find plenty of info online about using `dd` to clone OS drives.

Don't listen! It's MUCH faster to use `dump` and `restore` because you only copy the data, rather than copying all the blocks (empty or not).

**Part 1: Know where your source and destination drives are in the device list**

`lsscsi | grep sd*`

will show you a list of scsi devices and their associated letters. If you are lucky enough to be working with a hot-swapable box, then you can simply run that command before and then after you insert the drive--the newest device to show up is, of course, the drive you just inserted.

**Part 2: Prepare to dump**

1. Safety tip: assign variables for the destination and source devices. (Also, if you are doing this more than once, variablization allows you to reuse the commands.)

`SOURCE=/dev/sdx` `DEST=/dev/sdy`

2. A note on the source drive (the one you are copying from). If you are copying the current OS drive, it will (duh) already be mounted. If you are copying a different drive, it actually doesn't need to be mounted.
3. Copy the partition table of your source drive out to a file:
   `sfdisk -d $SOURCE > part_table`
4. Copy the part_table already stored in a file
   `sfdisk --force $DEST < part_table`
5. Zero out the boot sector: `dd if=/dev/zero of=${DEST}1 bs=512 count=1`
6. Make your filesystem (one partition at a time): 
   `mkfs -t ext4 ${DEST}1`
   `mkswap ${DEST}2`
7. Take a look: `parted $DEST --script print`
8. Copy the label of all non-swap partitions. Example: `tune2fs -L "/" /${DEST}1`

**Part 3: The dump | restore moment**

9. Make a directory to mount the destination device of the dump | restore. (As mentioned above, source device need not be mounted.)
   `mkdir -p /mnt/${DEST}1`
10. Mount the destination device:`mount -t ext4 ${DEST}1 /mnt/${DEST}1`
11. `cd` into the mount point:`cd /mnt/${DEST}1`
12. Dump and restore: `dump -a0f - /dev/${SOURCE}1 | restore -rf -`
    (*dump flags:* a=autosize; 0 (zero)=start at block 0; f = file, - = stdout; *restore flags:* r=rebuild; f=file; - = stdout)
13. The `dump | restore` should take just a few minutes.

**Part 4: use grub to install a boot loader onto the cloned drive**

14. Assuming you are copying an OS drive (i.e., a drive off which you boot a box), you need to install a boot loader.
15. Grub identifies disks as hd#, starting from 0 (NOT 1). The correspondence is easy: /dev/sda = hd0, /dev/sdb = hd1, etc.

    ```
     [root@drive-toaster /]# grub

     grub> root (hd1,0)  # use correct number for your disk!  
     root (hd1,0)   
     Filesystem type is ext2fs, partition type 0x83

     grub> setup (hd1) # use correct number for your disk!  
     setup (hd1)   
     Checking if "/boot/grub/stage1" exists... yes
     Checking if "/boot/grub/stage2" exists... yes
     Checking if "/boot/grub/e2fs_stage1_5" exists... yes
     Running "embed /boot/grub/e2fs_stage1_5 (hd1)"...  27 sectors are     embedded.
     succeeded
     Running "install /boot/grub/stage1 (hd1) (hd1)1+27 p
     (hd1,0)/boot/grub/stage2 /boot/grub/grub.conf"... succeeded
     Done.

     grub> quit
    ```

Comment: This should really be on super user.

Comment: This is good (for another site) but it needs to be in a Q&A format.